# Termite terminal audible bell setting is not working

Tags: terminal, xfce, manjaro

I am trying to configure the *Termite* Terminal to my liking; however, it seems that I cannot get the terminal to beep on a bell (`\a`) character.

Here is my `~/.config/termite/config` file:

```
[options]
allow_bold = true
audible_bell = true
bold_is_bright = true
cell_height_scale = 1.0
cell_width_scale = 1.0
clickable_url = true
hyperlinks = true
dynamic_title = true
font = Hermit 13
fullscreen = true
icon_name = terminal
mouse_autohide = true
scroll_on_output = false
scroll_on_keystroke = true
scrollback_lines = 10000
search_wrap = false
urgent_on_bell = true

browser = firefox

scrollbar = off


# ... trimmed the colors portion ...
```

The `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` envvar is not set, and the only other configuration file that I have on my system for *Termite* is the one located at `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/termite/config`; however, it's not even used, since my above config takes precedence.

In *urxvt*, which I also have installed on my system, executing `echo -ne '\a'` makes a bell sound, since I have configured this terminal with the *Bell-command* Perl extension. However, neither in *Termite* nor in the *Xfce Terminal* does this command does not trigger a bell sound.

I have confirmed that I am able to play sounds from *Termite* (e.g. `paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg` works as expected), but for some reason `echo -ne '\a'` makes no sound.

How can I enable audible bell in *Termite*?

P.S. I don't know if it matters, but I am running all this on Manjaro with the Xfce4 desktop environment.